# Unsort a list back to original sequence

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
aList = [2, 1, 4, 3, 5]

aList.sort()

=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

del aList[2]

=[1, 2, 4, 5]

**unsort the list back to original sequence with '3' deleted**

=[2, 1, 4, 5]
```

In reality I have a list of tuples that contain (Price, Quantity, Total).
I want to sort the list, allow the user to delete items in the list and
then put it back in the original order minus the deleted items.

One thing to note is that the values in the tuples can repeat in the list,
such as:

```
aList = [(4.55, 10, 45.5), (4.55, 10, 45.5), (1.99, 3, 5.97), (1.99, 1, 1.99)]
```

Comment: how do u want to sort tuple base on what?price or total

Comment: You can't *unsort* it. Similarly you can't [unbake a cake](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100623180655AAnBJFJ).

Comment: How can you unsort a sequence? You must change your mind to solve this problem, for example: find the 'target' element and delete it from the original sequence.

Comment: @frostnational "Unsort" is maybe an unfortunate choice of words, but one can achieve the intended effect by reordering a modified sequence by element positions remembered from a previous ordering. See my answer for a simple example.

Comment: @user4815162342 I already saw and upvoted it :) I've just pointed out that the way OP is thinking is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do an "unsort", the best you can do is:

```
aList = [2, 1, 4, 3, 5]

aList.remove(sorted(aList)[2])

>>> print aList
[2, 1, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Users are not going to remember the indexes, it is the program which must handle this scenario.

Comment: @vamosrafa, I'm sorry, I don't see the reason for a downvote. The  users don't have to do anything. What do you mean "remember"?

Comment: @vamosrafa I don't get what you mean. Actually this answer looks better than the other one. +1

Comment: @thefourtheye `remove` deletes only first occurrence of that value in a list, so duplicates won't get deleted.

Comment: @frostnational, Yes but as you can see, the OP is only deleting _1_ value at a specific index just as this answer is

Answer (score 9):

You cannot *unsort* the list but you could keep the original unsorted index to restore positions.

E.g.

```
from operator import itemgetter

aList = [(4.55, 10, 45.5), (4.55, 10, 45.5), (1.99, 3, 5.97), (1.99, 1, 1.99)]

# In keyList:
# * every element has a unique id (it also saves the original position in aList)
# * list is sorted by some criteria specific to your records
keyList = sorted(enumerate(aList), key = itemgetter(1))

# User want to delete item 1
for i, (key, record) in enumerate(keyList):
    if key == 1:
        del keyList[i]
        break

# "Unsort" the list
theList = sorted(keyList, key = itemgetter(0))

# We don't need the unique id anymore
result = [record for key, record in theList]
```

As you can see this works with duplicate values.

Answer (score 2):

#### Unsorting can be done

This approach is like others - the idea is to keep the original indices to restore the positions. I wanted to add a clearer example on how this is done.

In the example below, we keep track of the original positions of the items in `a` by associating them with their list index.

```py
>>> a = [4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> b = [(a[i], i) for i in range(len(a))]
>>> b
[(4, 0), (3, 1), (2, 2), (1, 3)]
```

`b` serves as a mapping between the list values and their indices in the unsorted list.

Now we can sort `b`. Below, each item of `b` is sorted by the first tuple member, which is the corresponding value in the original list.

```py
>>> c = sorted(b)
>>> c
[(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 0)]
```

There it is... sorted.

Going back to the original order requires another sort, except using the second tuple item as the key.

```py
>>> d = sorted(c, key=lambda t: t[1])
>>> d
[(4, 0), (3, 1), (2, 2), (1, 3)]
>>> 
>>> d == b
True
```

And now it's back in its original order.

One use for this could be to transform a list of non sequential values into their ordinal values while maintaining the list order. For instance, a sequence like `[1034 343 5 72 8997]` could be transformed to `[3, 2, 0, 1, 4]`.

```py
>>> # Example for converting a list of non-contiguous
>>> # values in a list into their relative ordinal values.
>>>
>>> def ordinalize(a):
...     idxs = list(range(len(a)))
...     b = [(a[i], i) for i in idxs]
...     b.sort()
...     c = [(*b[i], i) for i in idxs]
...     c.sort(key=lambda item: item[1])
...     return [c[i][2] for i in idxs]
...     
>>> ordinalize([58, 42, 37, 25, 10])
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Same operation

```py
>>> def ordinalize(a):
...     idxs = range(len(a))
...     a = sorted((a[i], i) for i in idxs)
...     a = sorted(((*a[i], i) for i in idxs),
...                key=lambda item: item[1])
...     return [a[i][2] for i in idxs]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to unsort a sorted list

```
import random
li = list(range(101))
random.shuffle(li)
```

Comment: This gave me a good laugh =).. This is definitely going to unsort any lists.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I recommend to sort a list, do something, then unsort back to the original ordering:

```
# argsort is the inverse of argsort, so we use that
# for undoing the sorting.
sorter = np.argsort(keys)
unsorter = np.argsort(sorter)

sorted_keys = np.array(keys)[sorter]

result = do_a_thing_that_preserves_order(sorted_keys)
unsorted_result = np.array(result)[unsorter]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same use case and I found an easy solution for that, which is basically random the list:

```
import random

sorted_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
unsorted_list = random.sample(sorted_list, len(sorted_list))
```